# JFrame's icon not displaying

Tags: java, swing

I've got a Java application with Swing's JFrame as a main GUI unit. I've set the icon to it via setIconImage(). When I run this program in NetBeans, everything works fine and the frame's icon displays. But when I compile it and try to run jar-file (with JRE7), the application has standard icon with Duke. How do I change that icon when running app outside NetBeans?

UPD:
OK, here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    URL imgUrl = Polygon.class.getResource("/imgs/icon.png");
    Image img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    f.setIconImage(img);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

UPD2:
I've added this line to the end of the code:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ImageIcon(img));
```

Everything's fine with the image! It loads! BUT it's not displayed as the icon.

Comment: Where is the code, preferably `SSCCE`?

Comment: Please give the corresponding code parts. Do you reference a static path to the icon? is your icon in your jar file after compilation?

Comment: There's no need in any code, because the code itself works fine (the frame has icon in NetBeans). I suspect, something's wrong with JRE.

Comment: The troubles are only when I run the compiled jar-file

Comment: My icon is in the JAR-file. I refer it via URL (getClass().getResource()). And than I download the icon via ImageIO.read(URL) and set it to frame via JFrame.setImageIcon(Image)

Comment: The critical code may indeed by useful to see where the problems might be...

Comment: First of all, you could just use ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(URL); it's better than Image... did you already open your jar using WinZip or similar and checked that the icon is there? Try to sysout the url and check if the path is correct

Comment: Is your Image folder located in the src folder ;

Comment: Xavjer, no, I can't use ImageIcon, because it's not Image's subclass

Comment: I always had problems in loading application resources in `main()`.  We cannot rely on the **context class-loader** to have been created by that time. OTOH your claim that it shows in a `JOptionPane` (when run as a Jar?) indicates the image **is** being found.  BTW - Where is that 'display with `JOptionPane` code'?  I 2nd @Reimeus call for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (as opposed to a code snippet).

Answer (score 2):

When you run the application from inside Netbeans, the files from your project folder are available, but if you run the compiled JAR yourself they may not.

Read this [example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/223.html) (note the comments) to load your image properly.

Comment: That's not the point. I use other images in my project, and I load them exactly the way I load this icon image and everything works outside netbeans. Except the icon image.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getClass().getResource("imgs/icon.png")`. It works for me. Note the difference between absolute and relative path. You may not need the leading `/`.